# Function to find all timeslots between 2 given times

Tags: php, function

I have an array of timeframes, for example these:

```
[
    start_time => 09:00,
    end_time => 11:00
    available => 1
],
[
    start_time => 11:00,
    end_time => 12:00
    available => 0
],
[
    start_time => 12:00,
    end_time => 18:00,
    available => 1
]
```

I need a function that finds if between times X and Y the user is available or not. How could I achieve that?

This is what I got so far:

```
private function findTimeframe($timeframes, $startTime, $endTime)
{
    if (count($timeframes) == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($timeframes[0]['start_time'] < $startTime && $timeframes[0]['end_time'] < $startTime) {
        array_shift($timeframes);
        return $this->findTimeframe($timeframes, $startTime, $endTime);
    }

    if ($timeframes[0]['end_time'] < $endTime) {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private function findTimeframe($timeframes, $startTime, $endTime)
{
    foreach ($timeframes as $timeframe) {
        if ($timeframe['available']) {
            continue; // if timeframe is avaiable, skip checking times
        }

        if (// $startTime is in the timeframe
            ($timeframe['start_time'] < $startTime && $startTime < $timeframe['end_time']) //
            // or $endTime is in the timeframe
            || ($timeframe['start_time'] < $endTime && $endTime < $timeframe['end_time'])
        ) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true; // not found any timeframe with available=0 and within $startTime / $endTime range
}
```

BTW: I would use http://php.net/strtotime in your place to convert date/time strings into timestamps.

Comment: It works good, thanks. But the fields are TIME not TIMESTAMP in the database. Isn't timestamp used for times that have both time and date?